# Mat Table is not displaying data on ngOnIt but after refresh its displaying

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular5

I'm using Angular Material with Angular.

My table does not display data on the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, but after I refresh the app it displays:
[image: Values are in my array but not displaying in the table]

Even `ChangeDetectorRef` doesn't affect the table.

Here is the template for the table:

```html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource"> 
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Phone">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{ user.phone }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="LastName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> LastName </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell   *matCellDef="let user" > {{ user.lastname}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let user; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

And here's the component's file:

```ts
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private userService: UserService){}
    displayedColumns = ['ID', 'FirstName', 'Phone', 'LastName'];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User>;
    users: User[] = [];
    ngOnInit() {
        this.users= this.userService.getUserList();
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    }
```

Here is a snippet of `UserService` for getting a user list:

```ts
getUserList() {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token});
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.get('/api/getallusers/', options)
     .map((data: Response) => {
         return data.json() as User[];
      }).toPromise().then(x => {
         this.userList = x;
      });
      return this.userList;
    }
```

Comment: use `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: @Und3rTow same result with ngafterviewInit

Comment: I have only done this with observables but i assume that your promise will reslove after the ngOnInit is done. And return an empty list at this stage.
You can also try to use markForCheck() instead of detectChanges()

Answer (score 2):

This issue was there with the **[`beta version`](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5917)** though and that could be resolved using **`detect changes.`**

In your case , the real issue is data is not getting assigned in ngOnit, you need to use Observables instead of Promise and subscribe inside the component, Change your service as follows,

```
 getPatients() {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('/api/getallpatients/', options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

and call it inside the component as,

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.patientService.getPatients().subscribe((data) => {
      this.patients = data;
      console.log('#####patients inside ngonit', this.patients);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.patients);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  Your code here.
  }
```