# Update mat-table contents by changing .filteredData property

Tags: angular, typescript

**UPDATE: $scope.$apply(); seems to be the right approach, but I'm using Angular6... how would I implement the same feature?**

I'm currently trying to update a table in a particular way. I do not wish to achieve this via the `.filter` property, custom pipes, etc, rather, I want to directly assign the data I wish to display to a property of the `dataSource`.

I've tried assigning `dataSource.filteredData` to data that I wish to display. However, even though `dataSource.filteredData` updates, the table fails to reflect such changes.

Am I changing the correct variable? How would I update viewable table contents by directly editing a property of the `dataSource`, i.e. through `.filteredData`?

Hope this makes sense, if not, please ask!

Comment: can you post your code?, also is it angular or angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is on angularjs, i recommend you to use **`$scope.$apply()`** This will force an update of the watches and a digest cycle.

Once you set the data to **`dataSource.filteredData`** call **`$scope.$apply();`**

**EDIT:**

Since you are using angular with typescript, you can do the same with **`detectChanges()`**

once you assign the data just call,

```
chRef.detectChanges();
```

You can read my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186828/mat-table-is-not-displaying-data-on-ngonit-but-after-refresh-its-displaying)**

Comment: Apologies, this is an angular CLI project that runs on typescript - could I do something similar to your suggestion with this setup?

Comment: @J.Tey you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186828/mat-table-is-not-displaying-data-on-ngonit-but-after-refresh-its-displaying

Comment: did that help to sort your issue?

Comment: great! glad to help!

Comment: Hi. I have the also tried to follow same thing in my filter function which sets the data in filteredData of MatTableDataSource, but it does not update the view. I debugged and the data is there. I basically manipulated the already filtered data which is my main scenario. Thanks in advance. I am working with Angular with Typescript.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've searched the equivalent to `$scope.$apply()` in Angular 2+ is doing it like this:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from 'angular/core';

constructor(private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef){
}
```

Then use:

```
chRef.detectChanges(); // whenever you need to force update view
```

after you set the data with `dataSource.filteredData`.